# IgniteCache: testdb - Connection is not available

Tags: spring, ignite

I created an Ignite Cache with the following configuration:

```
@Bean(name = Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM)
@Qualifier(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM)
public Ignite standardItemsIgniteConfiguration() {
    return Ignition.getOrStart(this.getIgniteConfiguration());
}

private IgniteConfiguration getIgniteConfiguration() {
    final CacheConfiguration<String, StandardItem> igniteCacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE);

    igniteCacheConfiguration.setName(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE);
    igniteCacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, StandardItem.class);
    igniteCacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    igniteCacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(false);
    igniteCacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    igniteCacheConfiguration.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);

    final IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM);
    igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(igniteCacheConfiguration);

    return igniteConfiguration;
}
```

My Spring Service creates the ignite cache, preloads data using the `IgniteDataStreamer` and provides a query to get all items:

```
@Service
public class DataService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataService.class.getName());

    private final IgniteCache<String, StandardItem> standardItemIgniteCache;

    public DataService(@Autowired @Qualifier(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM) Ignite standardItemIgnite) {
        logger.info("Call data service constructor");

        this.standardItemIgniteCache = standardItemIgnite.cache(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE);
        this.standardItemIgniteCache.clear();

        try (IgniteDataStreamer<String, StandardItem> streamer = standardItemIgnite.dataStreamer(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE)) {
            this.loadStandardItemCache(streamer);
        }
    }

    private void loadStandardItemCache(IgniteDataStreamer<String, StandardItem> streamer) {
        logger.info("Load standard items into ignite cache");

        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        Flux<StandardItem> items = new StandardItemDAO().getAllItems();

        items.doOnComplete(() -> logger.info("Loaded " + counter + " standard items into ignite cache")).subscribe(item -> {
            if (item != null) {
                counter.incrementAndGet();

                streamer.addData(item.getItemId(), item);
            }
        });
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Flux<StandardItem> getAllStandardItems(Map<String, String> params) {
        logger.info("get all standard items");

        String search = SearchHelper.toSearchString(params);

        logger.info("get all standard items for search params: " + search);

        return Flux.create(sink -> new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("lookup standard items cache");

            Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, StandardItem>> iterator = standardItemIgniteCache.iterator();

            logger.info("publish standard items from cache");

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                sink.next(iterator.next().getValue());
            }

            logger.info("publishing standard items from cache done");

            sink.complete();
        }).start());
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for round about 20 minutes. Within these 20 minutes every request and every query is working. But after round about 20 minutes every query failes with the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) ~[websocket-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.M6.jar!/:2.0.0.M6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterWithMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:95) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.M6.jar!/:2.0.0.M6]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:72) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.M6.jar!/:2.0.0.M6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar!/:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.sc.pps.provider.ProviderService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$594ecf1c.getAllStandardItems(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
        at io.sc.pps.provider.ProviderController.getAllStandardItems(ProviderController.java:39) ~[classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:207) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:154) ~[spring-orm-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-orm-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: testdb - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:603) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:193) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:149) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar!/:5.2.8.Final]
        ... 85 common frames omitted
```

What is the reason that there all of a sudden the queries do not work anymore and what is the so called `testdb` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAllStandardItems` method is marked with `@Transactional` annotation which doesn't make sense for at least these two reasons:

- You're not using Ignite transaction manager, so Spring starts transaction on some other database not related to Ignite. However, method itself only accesses Ignite.
- Ignite cache iteration is never transactional anyway, so even with Ignite transaction manager annotation will not make any difference.

Apparently the test fails when database `JpaTransactionManager` is pointed to can't be accessed. But obviously it is not needed for this method, so you should just remove the annotation to make it work.